# Google Play Store suddenly started crashing with a java.lang.StackOverflowError error

Tags: google-play-store

Today I discovered that I can no longer open Google Play Store on my Galaxy S4, running Sumsung's version of Android v4.2.2.

When I try to open Google Play Store, it opens, but shorty fails with the following stack trace:

```
I/Finsky  ( 6299): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.dp.a(1041): Starting LocationRefresher
I/Finsky  ( 6299): [1] com.google.android.finsky.selfupdate.f.a(166): Skipping DFE self-update. Local Version [80691500] >= Server Version [-1]
I/Finsky  ( 6299): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.ji.a(102): TOS is accepted (pref)
I/Finsky  ( 6299): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.dk.a(64): com.samsung.groupcast available because owned, overriding [restriction=7].
I/Finsky  ( 6299): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.dk.a(64): ma.wanam.xposed available because owned, overriding [restriction=7].
I/Finsky  ( 6299): [1] com.google.android.finsky.utils.dk.a(64): com.questvisual.wordlens available because owned, overriding [restriction=7].
D/AndroidRuntime( 6299): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299): java.lang.StackOverflowError
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:298)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp.e(SourceFile:1355)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.FinskyApp.e(SourceFile:1379)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:83)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.api.model.Document.Z(SourceFile:1105)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:317)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:62)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.v.a(SourceFile:335)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:261)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.installer.b.a(SourceFile:3159)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android.finsky.autoupdate.r.a(SourceFile:326)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6299):    at com.google.android
D/AndroidRuntime( 4557): Shutting down VM
```

I attempted to fix this by side-loading the latest Google Play Store APK (`6.9.15.G-all [0] 3104571`), but this did not fix the problem.

Considering that the infinite recursion is between `autoupdate` and `installer` packages, I assume this is some sort of bug that happens when Google Play Store tries to autoupdate something?

I am not sure how to recover from this situation, so any ideas would be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** I was able to get rid of this particular error by ***downgrading*** Google Play Store all the way to `6.3.20.B-all [0] 2734767`. However, although Google Play Store no longer crashes, a new error prevents me from actually downloading any content:

```
I/Finsky  (11347): [1] com.google.android.finsky.receivers.h.a(443): Request install of com.staircase3.opensignal v=120530 pri=2 for single_install
I/Finsky  (11347): [1] com.google.android.finsky.receivers.h.a(1184): Installer kick - starting com.staircase3.opensignal
I/Finsky  (11347): [1] com.google.android.finsky.receivers.ac.a(1177): Received VolleyError 922 (Error while retrieving information from server. [DF-DLA-15])
I/Finsky  (11347): [1] com.google.android.finsky.receivers.v.a(766): Cancel running installation of com.staircase3.opensignal (null)
```

Now, this `DF-DLA-15` error appears to be quite famous:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/play/pqV-NFm-qy8

I have tried all troubleshooting steps suggested in that thread, even the crazy-sounding ones. To be specific:

- I cleared Data and Cache for Google Play Store and Service
- Recreated and re-synced my Google Account
- Deleted Dalvik cache
- Unmounted the SD Card
- Deleted and recreated my payment info in Google Play Store

After all that, still getting `DF-DLA-15`

Comment: It seems like it thinks two packages are dependent on each other, or something along those lines.  Have you tried clearing the data for the Play Store and Google Play Services?

Comment: I have tried clearing the Cache and Data for both Play Store and Google Play Services, as well as clearing the Dalvik cache, although that was probably needless. I have also tried recreating and re-syncing my Google account.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error by DOWNGRADING Google Play Services all the way to 6.3.20.B-all [0] 2734767. But this still doesn't work... I'll update the post with more detail.

Comment: Maybe try removing your Google account(s) and adding a different one, just as a test.

Comment: Matthew, tried as you suggest to use a different Google account, and got a different problem. This time installing an app results in "Authentication is required. You need to sign into your google account", when I am already signed in and even defined a payment source. Clearing Data from Play Store and Services didn't help.

Comment: That is incredibly weird.  I'm pretty much out of ideas other than trying to upgrade to a new Android version with a custom ROM, which you may not want to do especially over one issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem with a suggestion from Brandon Heston, although I am not sure that my situation was exactly like his (see comments).

I fixed the problem by doing the following:

- Uninstalled the last 2 apps I installed (Sleep as Android and Hue Disco).
- Deleted Data for Google Play Store, Google Play Services, Google Account Manager and Google Services Framework
- Rebooted

After this the Google Play Store stopped crashing. However, unlike Brandon's situation, neither of the 2 apps I uninstalled have become unavailable for my version of Android, so I am not sure why this solution worked, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

I just had what seems to be the same problem happen to me a couple hours ago. I think an app I was using suddenly became outdated in the store without a possible version for my phone (s5 running 4.4.2). This app had a subscription tied to it so I'm not sure if that played any role. But I deleted said app and cleared cache and data on Google play store, Google services framework, and Google play services. Seems to work now.

Comment: How did you figure out which app to remove?

Comment: Well I was also getting an Unfortunately Google Play S has stopped working or something along those lines message continuously. I tried clearing cache and data on everything to no avail. I remember I started getting the notification when using a Map my run app by mapmyfitness (under armour). Then I couldn't load the store for more than 2 seconds. And the message. I uninstalled that app. Then Google play store opened and gave me the option to install and said I still have subscription. I restarted. No more issues. Went to the store after the reboot and no more option to install because

Comment: There was no compatible versions for my device and firmware anymore. So I more or less got lucky I suppose.

Comment: I didn't Install when it gave me the option after uninstalling. Restarted and that option was gone. So probably an auto update issue with compatibility.

Comment: Brandon, you were right! I uninstalled the last app I installed (Sleep as Android), and the original problem went away. Play Store no longer crashing, but still stuck on DF-DLA-15 :(. I'll post that as a separate topic though.